# Memory Leak al renderizar un largo arreglo de Objetos con VueJS

Tags: vuejs

estoy teniendo serios problemas de memoria al cargar una larga lista de objectos y al momento de renderizarla en mi aplicación VueJS, más precisamente en un V-FOR anidado, queda así:

```
<div id="contenido" ref="refContenido" class="q-mt-lg" v-show="votantes.length > 0">
  <div class="row q-mb-sm" v-for="(item, index) in votantes" :key="index">
    <div class="col-12 text-bold bg-teal-3" style="height: 35px; line-height: 35px; border: 1px solid black;">
      <p class="q-ml-sm">Provincia: {{ item.provincia }} ({{ CountByProvincias(item.municipios) }})</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12" v-for="(muns, idx1) in item.municipios" :key="idx1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-bold" style="height: 35px; line-height: 35px; border: 1px solid black;"><p class="q-ml-sm">Municipio: {{ idx1 }} - ({{ CountElectores(muns) }})</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 q-table-dense">
              <table class="q-table q-table-horizontal-separator" style="border: 1px solid black">
                <thead>
                <tr class="text-center text-bold bg-primary">
                  <th class="text-white">Nombres</th>
                  <th class="text-white">Cédula</th>
                  <th class="text-white">Teléfono</th>
                  <th class="text-white">Recinto</th>
                  <th class="text-white">Residencia</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(voters, idx2) in muns" :key="idx2">
                  <td class="text-center">{{ voters.nombres }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{ voters.cedula }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{ voters.telefono }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{ voters.recinto }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{ voters.municipioVive + ', ' + voters.provinciaVive }}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

No logro indetificar en el Snapshot de Chrome, estoy seguro es la forma de cargar esa información, si es así por favor indíquenme la mejor manera de mostrar esa info.

Saludos

Comment: ¿Una lista larga es cuántos elementos? Podrías por favor, añadir  el error que te muestra la consola del navegador?

Comment: No muestra error, la lista puede llegar a tener 10,000 filas de manera anidada, es solo que me consume muchisima memoria y tarda mucho congelada.